# Options Picker Placeholder is null Budibase

Tags: budibase

The following logic. A person searches for a product number. The product number has different attributes, for example location. You are able to change the location of the product number with an options picker after you have searched for it.

If there doesn't exist a location for the product number, the Placeholder string is displayed "Choose a location" in the options picker. If there already exists a location for the product number, the placeholder string is "null" in the options picker.

The functionality in both cases is the same. I can still select a location, and switch to it.

Does anyone know why null is displayed as default, instead of the Placeholder string?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem occurred to my app, I used a javascript function that returned a integer. But budibase expected a string, if you convert the integer to a string it should work.

Example if you use the javascript functionality:

```js
return `${1}`;

or

return (1).toString();
```